# Reading binary-file constructed with C in Python 2.7 is causing problems

Tags: c, python-2.7

could you please help me with a file-reading problem?

I have the following file structure information of a binary file constructed with C.

```
import numpy as np 



8 Bytes uint64_t name1
for (name1) {
    8 bytes uint64_t name2
    8 bytes unint64_t name3
    for name2 {
        8 bytes uint64_t name4     
        4 bytes int32_t name5             #this are the bytes not correctly interpreted by my routine
        52 x 4 bytes float name6
        4 bytes float name7
    }
}
```

I wrote in Python the following routine to read that:

```
      start_byte = 8    #start after 8 bytes
      blocksize  = 224  #sum up all bytes of the data block 'dt'


      dt = np.dtype([
                    ('name4', np.uint64),
                    ('name5', np.int32),
                    ('name6_7', np.float32, (53,)),
                    ])

        openfile = open(mypath,'rb')

        name1 = np.fromstring(openfile.read(8), dtype = np.uint64)

        i=0
        while i<name1:

            #first value: read name2 8 bytes
            openfile.seek(start_byte)
            name2 = np.fromstring(openfile.read(8), dtype = np.uint64)       

            #goto next value: read name3 8 bytes 
            start_byte=start_byte + 8            
            openfile.seek(start_byte)
            name3 = np.fromstring(openfile.read(8), dtype = np.uint64)

            #goto data-block: read 224 bytes at once times name2 (count)         
            start_byte=start_byte + 8
            openfile.seek(start_byte)

            #here I used my structure with the proper data formats
            data_block = np.fromfile(openfile, dtype=dt, count=name2)
            data_block_array.extend(data_block)

            #do all that again for the next block of value name2  
            count = count + name2     
            start_byte= start_byte + name2*block_size

            i+=1
```

OK, everything seems fine at the beginning, but I discovered that **"name5"** the int32_t are causes trouble. I could see the problem there, since the output for "name5" should be **0 or 1**. And I **get some values between 0.3 to 13000** whatsoever. I seems also that only this column of the data file causes trouble and the author of the C routine **changed the "name5" data format from int8_t to int32_t**!

QUESTIONS:

- Do I not properly address the data format? In that case what to use
  for Python for: C uint64_t, int32_t, float etc?
- Where is the error and how can I find out if the binary format is
  correctly read?
- Has this problem something do to with going from C to Python. Is this
  problem caused by the C-routing converting ASCII into binary file, or
  is it rather on my end of the programme not using Python correctly? (More direct: which fault is it ;-) ... )

I really appreciate your help and looking forward your answer!

Thanks

*fly*

Comment: Look at the file using a tool like hexdump.  That way you can both agree on which side has the problem.

Comment: thanks Steve, I am looking into that ...

Comment: I believe ```struct.unpack``` is your friend, in this case.